# No route to DNS server from Docker container

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, docker, linux-networking

Even though I can successfully ping a host from a Docker container (i.e. `docker run busybox ping -c 1 216.58.207.206`), requests involving a DNS lookup result in a timeout (e.g. `docker run nslookup google.com`).

I've looked at suggestions from [this NPM Github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16661), namely editing `/etc/hosts`, connections from different networks, and rebooting the machine, all without any success.

Docker to Docker connection issues seem [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39937496/dns-server-in-docker-container) [be](https://forums.docker.com/t/no-route-to-host-network-request-from-container-to-host-ip-port-published-from-other-container/39063) [common](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/522), however, my issue deals with Docker to DNS connection and is distinct from these issues (even though the error message is similar).

I've also tried [Robin Winslow's Fix Docker's networking DNS config](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/) however, explicitly specifying the local or global DNS server fails.

```
$ docker run --dns <local DNS IP> busybox nslookup google.com
>>> nslookup: write to <local DNS IP>: No route to host
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox nslookup google.com
>>> nslookup: write to '8.8.8.8': No route to host
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Docker environments can be so different that without providing additional information like: Docker version, Operating System, its difficult to help.

Comment: I provided the particular Docker container used (busybox). My docker version is 19.03.12 and I'm using Fedora 32 64 bit version.

Answer (score 2):

## Quick Fix

For anyone else having Fedora 31/32 Docker issues I suggest following the [Fedora Magazine's Guide on Docker and Fedora 32](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/)

For me personally the issue was caused by the firewall blocking docker connections and the following command fixed it:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
sudo firewall-cmd --reload # reload the firewall rules
```

## Moving to Podman

Docker requires a root daemon, which creates a [security](https://mkdev.me/en/posts/dockerless-part-1-which-tools-to-replace-docker-with-and-why) [concern](https://www.oreilly.com/content/five-security-concerns-when-using-docker/). The issue can be mitigated by switching over to [Podman](https://podman.io/) and using it with the [same commands as Docker](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/02/21/podman-and-buildah-for-docker-users/):

```
podman run --dns 8.8.8.8 busybox nslookup google.com
```